# Multiset of pair, find

Tags: c++, std-pair, multiset

I need to find and erase a value in mutliset of pair sorted by my own function. Apparently, .find always returns the iterator to the end, not to the searched value. Any tips? This is the function :

```
struct cmp
{
  bool operator() (const para &a, const para &b)
  {
    if (a.first > b.first) return false;
    if (b.first > a.first) return true;

    if (a.second < b.second) return false;
    else return true;
  }
};
```

Edit:

```
kolej.insert(para(0,2));
if (kolej.find(para(0,2)) == kolej.end()) printf("Jej");
```

Even if I do something like that, where para is `pair<int,int>` and kolej is `multiset`, it will always proceed to print "Jej"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparator will evaluate to `true` for equal objects. You should change

```
if (a.second < b.second) return false;
else return true;
```

to

```
return b.second > a.second;
```